# bash process using all cpu

Tags: systemd

I have processes named `bash64` which are using all my CPU.

If I kill them, it reappears. Their ancestor is a bash process which have systemd as own ancestor.

[image]

[image]

How to find which process/ systemd unit are running that ?

```
root@srv1:~# ls -al /proc/$(pidof bash64 | awk '{print $1}')/exe
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 juil. 29 18:44 /proc/11655/exe -> /root/.tmp00/bash64

root@srv1:~# ls .tmp00
27d96f548d2d99d032c4v1.2.0  bash  bash64  bash.pid  cfg  cfgi  uuid
```

If I remove the .tmp00 dir, it reappears immediatly.

My system is a baremetal Ubuntu 20.04 on ext4/ssd. I got some issues with DNS resolving recently but which came from my router configuration (but I may have broke something on my desktop).

Comment: Feel free to ask for more details, command outputs

Comment: There is no `bash64` in the [official repository](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=focal&arch=any&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=bash64). So you have to determine its full path by `which bash64` or `ls -al /proc/$(pidof bash64 | awk '{print $1}')/exe` and origin.

Comment: What operating system is it? Linux distro and version? What file system are you using for your root file system (standard ext4 or something else)? What kind of drive is it (SATA, NVMe or something else)? Is it running on metal or in a virtual machine? -- Can you remember what you did before this happened? What tool or task did you run?

Comment: Your edits in the question does not give me any clue. Maybe someone else will find something. -- Have you tried to shutdown and wait a while? Will these processes appear again after you boot again after 60 seconds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your system has been compromised by a cryptominer, probably a SSH worm. I suggest following these steps:

1. Disconnect your computer from any network
2. Copy the `bash64` file and other files in the same folder to a USB drive, remove the execution attribute (`chmod a-x file`) from those files.
3. Copy your personal data from the compromised machine to an appropriate backup device, do not use a network to do this, use USB.
4. Do a clean re-install of the compromised computer.
5. Upload the files from step 2 to VirustTotal

Comment: You are right. I have found that: https://otx.alienvault.com/indicator/file/a5c105dd45f6c51a1281c37f79f3d16e93a0f5ffcdb5a25f4f6a025bc7a2f1b6

Comment: I exposed a ssh port with a very simple password because it was normaly allowed only inside the local network.